# How to make responsive image background with fixed height?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to know how to make the image responsive with fixed height?

for the reference, this is how i want my image to be responsive

http://www.mariaelenabenetti.it/it/

Im using bootstrap with image responsive, but it makes the image smaller when the screen get smaller too.

What i want is when the screen get smaller the image stay on the same size but it can responsively crop itself to fit the screen.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [**Media Queries**](https://www.google.se/search?q=media+queries+css&oq=media+queries&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.1869j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @user3535422 the example you showed doesn't have a fixed height, it just uses `background-size: cover;` for the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.image { 
  background: url(yourpath/image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same doubt.

In this another example the image is not a background, at least I guess it. Look to the second slider of this page.

http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/development/camera_1.0.6/demo/basic.htm